# Where does the "sich" go?

Tags: word-order

Attempting to translate

> I don’t think you’ll have to bother much with the controls.

I said:

> Ich glaube, du wirst dich um die Steuerungen nicht viel brauchen zu scheren.

but then thought that it might need to be:

> Ich glaube, du wirst nicht viel brauchen, dich um die Steuerungen zu scheren.

Are both these correct possibilities, strictly with respect to the grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb order of the first example might be ok in some dialects, but in standard German the infinitive (here: *brauchen*) that directly belongs to the modal verb (here: *wirst*) belongs to the end, and all further dependencies before that:

> Ich glaube, du wirst dich um die Steuerungen nicht viel zu scheren brauchen.

The second example doesn't work at all with the word brauchen.

If you look at it purely grammatically, it might be acceptable if you insert  an additional "es" standing in for the object before the actual object comes in the form of the extended infinitive:

> Ich glaube, du wirst **es** nicht brauchen, dich viel um die Steuerungen zu scheren.

The meaning is a different one though, because only the construction "etwas nicht zu tun brauchen" has that meaning of "to not have to do something". In contrast, "es (nicht) brauchen, etwas zu tun" doesn't really exist in standard German. In colloqial German, it means having a/no desire to do something. So this sentence would actually mean "You won't have much desire to bother with the controls."

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt:

> Ich glaube, du wirst dich um die Steuerungen nicht viel brauchen zu scheren.

is almost correct, but in normal prose, you should put *brauchen* last, so it should be:

> Ich glaube, du wirst dich um die Steuerungen nicht viel zu scheren brauchen.

This is a general rule with modal verbs, e.g. *das hättest du nicht tun sollen* etc. The word order *brauchen zu scheren* would be acceptable in poetry. You can, for example, see it in the common expression *es hat nicht sollen sein* (which is a quote from the famous [Trompeterlied](https://www.trompeter-von-saeckingen.de/scheffel/trompeterlied.htm)).

The future tense is fine, even if not necessary.

Note that the controls, e.g. in an airplane cockpit, are *Bedienelemente*. *Steuerung* is what you do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. It must be

> Ich glaube nicht, dass du dich um die ganzen Hebel viel zu scheren brauchst.

No Futur I tense. That extra complication is not needed. Also *controls* has no direct counterpart in German. You have to describe it. I picked *die ganzen Hebel — all those levers*.

If you are unsure about the order of verbs, it's exactly reversed as in English. And then, as the last step, if you have a main clause, you have to move the last verb stem to V2 position.

And, more natural is

> Ich glaube nicht, dass du dich um die ganzen Hebel viel scheren musst.

The German modals are more straightforward to use than the English ones.

---

That last sentence

> Ich glaube, du wirst nicht viel brauchen, dich um die Steuerungen zu scheren.

is grammatically correct but gibberish nevertheless. It means something along the lines of *I think you don't have to provide much to bother with the control systems.*

Comment: I would like to consider the grammar, independently of all the many other criticisms that could be leveled against this German.

Comment: I beg your pardon?

Comment: I am just wondering if the grammar, considered by itself, is or is not correct in these sentences?

Comment: The grammar of your first example isn't correct because it has the wrong verb order. Also, the meaning is slightly off. The grammar of your second example is correct but the meaning is completely off.